# Mac book pro swap function key usage and F * keys using boot camp

Tags: windows, keyboard, macbook, boot-camp, function-keys

Is there a way to auto imply the function key being pressed.  Or swap it's use.

I basically want F1 to be for F1 and F2 to be for F2 by default.  If I want to lighten or darken my screen then I will press the function key (fn).

I'm in Windows using boot camp by the way.

Comment: @quack: Why osx?

Comment: @macbooknewb: [osx] is the tag for Apple's operating system; [mac] is the tag for Apple's hardware.  since you're trying to change a setting it seemed more appropriate, especially since the answer suggests this is in your control panel, but i'm not a Mac expert so i could've gotten it wrong.  feel free to edit and change it back if [mac] is more appropriate; mostly i was trying to add the other tags.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a bootcamp icon inside your control panel, which should allow you to control this setting.

Comment: Thank you the option was there to swap fn key!!!!!!!!!!!!!!